# How to categorize uber providers?

Tags: ios, uber-api

If we check Uber iOS app in US then the providers are shown category wise.

UberX and UberXL are in the category of UberX,UberBlack and SUV are in the category of UberBlack.

How can we achieve that categorization?

We are using [rides-api](https://uber.readme.io/docs/tutorials-rides-api) and from response we can not find any parameter on which we can categorize them.

Comment: It's the 'display_name' value from the https://uber.readme.io/docs/v1-products end point.

Comment: I don't think so. We are getting "display_name": "UberBLACK" & "display_name": "UberSUV". How can we say they will go in UberBLACK category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately as of right now we don't offer parent groupings of Uber products in the /products endpoint. However, we are actively working on the /products endpoint. Please stay tuned to [devblog.uber.com](http://devblog.uber.com) for future updates.

Best,

Richie

Comment: Thanks Richie for update. I will follow the link you suggested for latest information.